# Unable to execute continuous adb commands from java application

Tags: java, android, adb

I want to make an application installed at android rooted device as a system app from java application..
for that I have to execute following commands

```
adb remount

adb shell

su

cd /data/app/

ls com.mypackage *
```

then have to check if app with this package name is installed after that have to execute following commands

```
mv com.mypackage.apk /system/app/com.mypackage.apk

exit 

exit 

adb reboot
```

any Idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: Please do mention the problem before rating it negative....

Comment: Yeah, what is the exact problem? What doesn't work? I didn't vote negative :D

Comment: @Ty221 I want to execute above commands continuously because the  execution of each line is related with previous .... how can achieve that prgrammatically...

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("statement") is used to run a command in java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using process builder in your application to run the adb commands.

**Example**

```
String[] command = {"ls", "-s"}; // Mention your list of commands here

  StringBuilder cmdReturn = new StringBuilder();

  try {
   ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
   Process process = processBuilder.start();

   InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
   int c;
            while ((c = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
                cmdReturn.append((char) c);
            }

            prompt.setText(cmdReturn.toString());

  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Comment: String[] command = {path+"app_assets\\adb.exe","shell","su","cd /data/app/","ls com.my*"};       does not list any package where from cmd with same command it list packages.....  what would be the  problem?

Comment: how did you describe "prompt"?